# problems with mysql_num_rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-num-rows

for some reason i can not understand im having troubles with mysql_num_rows.

Heres the script:

```
$notquery = 'SELECT * FROM notification WHERE uid = 1 AND read = 0 
AND tipo = post 
OR tipo = subpost OR tipo = logros';

$notQuery = (mysql_query($notquery));

$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($notQuery);
```

error:

```
Warning:  mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource
```

Comment: Use `print mysql_error()` right after mysql_query to find possible problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sql is full with syntax error, try this

```
SELECT * FROM notification 
WHERE 
uid = 1 AND 
`read` = 0 AND 
tipo in('post', 'subpost', 'logros');
```

Comment: Actually his query was syntactically(?) correct. `tipo`, `post`, `subpost` and `logros` might be all columns. And the mixed `OR` and `AND` is weird =) but not syntactically wrong.

Comment: But maybe `read` is a reserved word... Which would make it syntactically wrong again. I give up.

Comment: he forget to quote the string ... I discover that when editing the question, not even mentioned the logically error on using `OR`, indeed `READ` is a reserved word

Comment: so the problem is the word READ?

Comment: yes, beside that, you should quote the string (`post,subspot,logros`) and your logic for `OR` is going to include any notification where the tipo is subpost or logros

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you have an error in the query execution.
Try adding `or die(mysql_error())` to debug what's going wrong...

update the code to :
`$notQuery = mysql_query($notquery) or die(mysql_error());`

Answer (score 0):

You input a string into `mysql_num_rows` =)

You use `$notquery` and `$notQuery` mixed... That must be the silliest thing I've ever seen.

Try this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT .....';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo mysql_error()."\n";
$numRows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Obviously, this might produce the same error, since you don't check for errors :) `$result` might not be a MySQL resource (it might be `FALSE`).

Comment: sry, i copied a wrong version of the script... i actually used notQuery

Comment: no ...it just reassign the execute results back to `$notQuery`

Comment: @ajreal He updated his question =) And the 'naming convention' is still silly. Bugs are programmers faults (duh) and they happen - among(st?) other reasons - because of these things: unsensible variable names.